# What happens if a Wizard casts Antimagic Field while under the effects of Time Stop?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Another player in one of my games recently suggested an interesting tactic for capturing opponents inside an [Antimagic Field](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm): Doing it inside a [Time Stop](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/timeStop.htm).

But, we are not sure what exactly what happens when you use your rounds of apparent time to cast an Antimagic Field whose area includes the caster.

There is one defined interaction between the spells:

> You cannot enter an area protected by an antimagic field while under the effect of time stop.

But that leaves out the possibility that the Antimagic Field is created by the caster. So what happens?

I'd prefer answers that reference rules text.

Comment: The DM throws a book at you for making his head hurt.

Comment: He actually didn't, surprisingly enough. We decided to ask if someone had a clue as to how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 6):

## It's Not as Much Fun as It Should Be

The range of the 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*time stop*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/timeStop.htm) [trans] (*PH* 294) is [personal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#range). The 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*anti-magic field*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm) [abjur] (*PH* 200) says that "it prevents the functioning of any magic items *or spells* within its confines." Emphasis mine.

Thus the spell *time stop* is suppressed until the duration of the spell *anti-magic field* expires.

Comment: And since *time stop* will run out long before the *anti-magic field* will, it's **really** useless.

Comment: Except Time Stop has a duration of "instantaneous".

Comment: @Frodalf The *D&D 3.5* spell [*time stop*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/timeStop.htm) has the entry *Duration: 1d4+1 rounds (apparent time); see text.*

Answer (score 3):

### Time Stop as a Delivery System

This is a very standard high-optimization tactic.  Against a spellcasting enemy with contingent spells or the ability to use *Celerity* or similar effects to avoid being closed with, using *Time Stop* to walk up to them and then an *Antimagic Field* to shut down their ability to escape (as well as all buff spells and spellcasting ability) is one of the few ways to deliver the AMF without Readied actions, *Celerity* or the like getting in the way.

As for the interaction, it's covered under the basic text of AMF.  Any active spells within it's area of effect with a duration are suppressed for the duration of the AMF - so the Time Stop's duration is suppressed.  This will pretty much only come up if you have a way to dismiss an AMF or it gets hit by a *Disjunction*.

The specific interaction with readied actions and the like is that the readied action activates, but whatever spell would be used to escape (such as *Teleport*) is instead ineffective, as the caster is already within the radius of the antimagic field (and they can't use it before the field goes up, as the caster is in a time stop until that point).